# Deleting object part of a Many-to-Many relationship with EntityManager returns error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a schema with a Many-to-Many relationship between entities "User" and "Role" mapped as follows.

Role entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $users;
```

and the User entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_roles")
 * 
 * @var ArrayCollection $userRoles
 */
protected $userRoles;
```

When I try to delete a role object with the following code,

```
$role = $em->getRepository('ACMEDefaultBundle:Role')->find($id);
$em->remove($role);
$em->flush();
```

I am getting a Doctrine Exception

> ErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: roles in /media/sf_sandbox/aalcodev/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 964 (uncaught exception) at /media/sf_sandbox/aalcodev/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 964

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: please do not use these words in titles: 'Problem'. See [Writing Good Titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/writing-good-titles/10648#10648)

Comment: Which part of the error message is hard for you to understand? Where is the index called roles?

Comment: @hakre Sorry. First time posting here, thanks for the link. I don't have an index "roles". When I run 'schema:update", I get three tables created - users, roles and users_roles. I can add and update 'roles' just fine with the EntityManager. I get the error when I try the delete. I am also able to do the delete with Doctrine's DBAL. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, probably. The error you see is likely a standard PHP notice converted into an [`ErrorException`](http://php.net/ErrorException). Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770836#12770836 for a first introduction to the error. As this happens in the doctrine codebase, check the exact doctrine version you're using and add it to your question for further info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `mappedBy="roles"` to `mappedBy="userRoles"`. "Mapped by" should point to other side's property name...